# How the google tag manager container ID is generated?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Do you know maybe how the container's ID (GTM-XXXX) is generated? Is it completely random or is derived from the associated account?

Comment: Looks like it is random

Comment: Im curious to know why u would like to know this and how can be useful?